# Granger-causality and impulse response functions yield conflicting results

Tags: granger-causality, impulse-response

I have a VAR model with two sets of variables, X and Y. Granger causality tests say that X granger causes Y but not the other way around.

However, the impulse response functions suggest that the variables in Y systematically affect the variables in X in a statistically significant and positive fashion more often and with higher magnitude than the other way around. I find this extremely unintuitive.

While it is true that Granger causality is pretty much a wald test on coefficients and impulse responses are based on innovations to the structural term, it is also true that the impulse response functions are themselves a function of the estimated coefficients...

The only explanation I can find for this is that the standard errors on which the wald (granger causality) tests are based on tend to be very large for coefficients with large magnitude and smaller for coefficients with "relatively" small magnitude, so that we have significance (and hence granger causality) for variables associated with relatively low coefficients and not for variables with relatively high coefficients (because the standard errors are larger more than proportionally).

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear. I am using a VAR(1) with 4 variables.  In that case, as documented by Lutkepohl (1993) and Dufourt and Renault (1998), granger causality cannot substitute impulse response conclusions as variable x can affect variable y 2 or 3-steps-ahead through another (endogenous) variable z. But the results are inconsistent between the (1 lag) granger-causality tests and the 1-period ahead (not instantaneous) results of the impulse responses

Comment: This might be of interest: http://monde.cirano.qc.ca/~dufourj/Web_Site/Dufour_Tessier_1993_EL_ImpulseResponseAnalysis.pdf